# Template heap/priority-queue data structure with update-key operation

Tags: c++, beginner, heap, priority-queue

I implemented the following priority-queue/heap with an update-key operation. The update key uses the map from STL, which still requires `lg(n)` time for lookup. However, replacing it with an `unordered_map` would require the client program to write hash and equal operations for each class, which is a problem in my case.

```
#ifndef IZ_HEAP_H
#define IZ_HEAP_H

#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class IzHeap {
  class IzHeapItem {
    int key;
    T item;
  public:
    IzHeapItem(const int key, const T& item)
      : key(key), item(item) {}
    T getItem() const {return item;}
    int getKey() const {return key;}
    void updateKey(const int newKey) {key = newKey;}
    void updateItem(const T& newItem) {item = newItem;}
    IzHeapItem& operator=(const IzHeapItem& heapItem) {
      this->key = heapItem.getKey();
      this->item = heapItem.getItem();
      return *this;
    }
  };
  std::vector<IzHeapItem> heap;
  std::map<T, int> itemToHeapIndex;
  int leftChild(const int index) const {return index*2 + 1;}
  int rightChild(const int index) const {return index*2 + 2;}
  int parent(const int index) const {return (index - 1)/2;}
  void heapSwap(const int i, const int j) {
    /*
    IzHeapItem temp = heap[i];
    heap[i] = heap[j];
    heap[j] = temp;
    */
    std::swap(heap[i], heap[j]);

    itemToHeapIndex[getItem(i)] = i;
    itemToHeapIndex[getItem(j)] = j;
  }
  int getKey(const int index) const {return heap[index].getKey();}
  T getItem(const int index) const {return heap[index].getItem();}
protected:
  void shiftUp(const int index) {
    int largest{index}, p{parent(index)};
    if (p >= 0 && getKey(p) > getKey(index)) {
      largest = p;
    }
    if (largest != index) {
      heapSwap(largest, index);
      shiftUp(largest);
    }
  }
  void shiftDown(const int index) {
    int smallest{index}, lc{leftChild(index)}, rc{rightChild(index)};
    if (lc < heap.size() && getKey(lc) < getKey(smallest)) {
      smallest = lc;
    }
    if (rc < heap.size() && getKey(rc) < getKey(smallest)) {
      smallest = rc;
    }
    if (smallest != index) {
      heapSwap(smallest, index);
      shiftDown(smallest);
    }
  }
public:
  T extract() {
    assert(heap.size() > 0);
    heapSwap(0, heap.size() - 1);
    T item = heap.back().getItem();
    heap.pop_back();
    itemToHeapIndex.erase(item);
    shiftDown(0);
    return item;
  }
  T peak() {
    return heap[0];
  }
  bool empty() {
    return heap.size() == 0;
  }
  void insert(const T& item, const int key) {
    heap.push_back(IzHeapItem(key, item));
    itemToHeapIndex[item] = key;
    shiftUp(heap.size()-1);
  }
  void updateKey(const T& item, const int newKey) {
    assert(itemToHeapIndex.count(item) > 0);
    int index = itemToHeapIndex[item];
    int oldKey = getKey(index);
    heap[index].updateKey(newKey);
    if (newKey > oldKey) {
      shiftDown(index);
    }
    else {
      shiftUp(index);
    }
  }
  void heapify(const std::vector<T>& items, const std::vector<int>& keys) {
    assert(items.size() == keys.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
      heap.push_back(IzHeapItem(keys[i], items[i]));
      itemToHeapIndex[items[i]] = i;
    }
    for (int i = heap.size()/2 - 1; i >=0; --i) {
      shiftDown(i);
    }
  }
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const IzHeap<T>& heap) {
    for (auto& hi : heap.heap) {
      out << "(" << hi.getKey() << "->" << hi.getItem() << "), ";
    }
    return out;
  }
};

#endif
```

Please comment on any improvements that can be done on this code. This is my first time posting on code review, so please let me know of any norms I should follow.

Answer (score 1):

1. `peak()` should be returning a const reference. same goes for `getItem()`.
2. `Extract()` should not return anything. Having two functions to read the head just begs for someone to accidentally call `Extract()` when they meant `peak()`.
3. Why is key forced to be an `int`? It could easily be a separate template parameter.
4. `heap.push_back(IzHeapItem(keys[i], items[i]));` should be `heap.emplace_back(keys[i], items[i]);` instead.
5. you should do a `heap.reserve()` at the top of `heapify()`
6. Heapifying a vector<> containing the same item twice would break this pretty badly. You should guard against this.
7. Unless you intend to call `heapify()` multiple times in a row, that should just be a constructor. Otherwise, I would rename that function `addToHeap()`
8. I prefer to avoid using the `[]` operator on maps in general unless I specifically want a "insert-or-replace" logic. There's a bunch of logic to handle creating a new instance, which assumes the value type of the map has a default constructor.

so:

```
itemToHeapIndex[items[i]] = i;
```

becomes

```
itemToHeapIndex.emplace(items[i], i);
```

and

```
assert(itemToHeapIndex.count(item) > 0);
int index = itemToHeapIndex[item];
```

becomes

```
auto found = itemToHeapIndex.find(item);
assert(found != itemToHeapIndex.end()); // Bonus! no additional lookup in debug
int index = found->second;
```

Super minor detail:

The `peak()` function name made me squint. Traditionally, `peek()` means "see the next value that will come out of the datastructure", which is what happens here. This is not really a problem you have to fix, more of an observation. I would personally have used `top()` and `pop()` to match established standards.

Comment: I'm not sure that `peak()` is a typo - isn't it the top (apex) of the heap?

Comment: @TobySpeight I've never even considered it, thanks! I'll fix the review.

Comment: When I said "not sure", I meant it literally - I spent a minute or two trying to decide, before concluding that it really could be either!

Comment: @TobySpeight That's enough for me to give OP the benefit of the doubt.